# Strange behavior in hive column aliases

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I am trying to build some hive (0.9) queries from an application which allows users to specify column name aliases.

I found that whenever the column alias is two characters long and is a digit followed by 'b' or 'B' then it gives the error: "cannot recognize input near 'AS' '2b' ',' in selection target"

Queries that don't work:

```
select t1.emp_id as 1b from someTable t1;
select t1.emp_id as 2b from someTable t1;
select t1.emp_id as 1B from someTable t1;
```

Queries that work:

```
select t1.emp_id as 1b1 from someTable t1;
select t1.emp_id as 1ba from someTable t1;
select t1.emp_id as 1c from someTable t1;
```

Is this a known issue in Hive? I could not find any JIRA issues that relate to such errors.

Comment: I just fired a similar query on my hive installation and it worked fine!

Comment: which Hive version are you using?

Comment: The issue is specifically with the pattern "[0-9]b|B"

Comment: Fascinating.  I can reproduce with Hive 0.12

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I'm pretty sure I found it.  The hive parser is recognizing this as a `ByteLengthLiteral` which is defined as the following:

```
ByteLengthLiteral
    :
    (Digit)+ ('b' | 'B' | 'k' | 'K' | 'm' | 'M' | 'g' | 'G')
    ;
```

I tried the same statement replacing `b` with `k`, `m`, and `g` and got the same error.

And for the sake of information, an identifier (`as [identifier]`) is defined as...

```
Identifier
    :
    (Letter | Digit) (Letter | Digit | '_')*
    | '`' RegexComponent+ '`'
    ;
```

Which seems like it should work, except that the `ByteLengthLiteral` has already been processed and so this fails to recognize the identifier.

Answer (score 2):

climbage gave a great answer on why this is happening; here's an answer on how to work around it - just use backticks, like so:

```
select t1.emp_id as `1b` from someTable t1;
```

Comment: Thanks! I think its better to use backticks on all identifiers from the generator application.